# facing is not a function error, but it is on Angular

Tags: angular, function, setinterval

i'm working on a html, css, js slider and i'm facing a strange error.
I'm working on angular

this is the error

```
    core.js:6479 ERROR TypeError: this.slideFunction is not a function
    at autoSlide (home.component.ts:32)
    at timer (zone.js:2561)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406)
    ......................................
    ......................................
```

**And this is how my code looks like**

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
      counter:number = 1;
      timer: any;

      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit(): void {

        //change the current slide to the next one after 8 secondes by calling the autoSlide function
        this.timer = setInterval(this.autoSlide,8000);

      }


      autoSlide() {
       this.counter += 1;
       this.slideFunction(this.counter);
      }

      //Function that handle the change
      slideFunction(slideNumber: number): void{
   
        My logic goes there...

      }
      }
```

Can someone show where am i doing wrong ?
Thank you

Answer (score -1):

This kind of error is related to type of string or number.
You should check the data type. For example, if it is a number, you should convert it to string using toString() function first before anything else.

Answer (score -2):

You are calling the `slidefunction()` before the same being defined.

First write the function, then call it.

Comment: The order of methods defined in a class does not matter